# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils.benchmark'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensorboard, torchvision

I have been trying to use the torch benchmark module for profiling the code. Verified that all required imports are in place:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torch.utils.benchmark
```

Also, these are the versions installed:

```
torch ->  1.4.0
torchvision -> 0.2.1
tensorflow ->  1.12.0
tensorflow-gpu -> 1.12.0
tensorboard -> 2.5.0
```

But I still get error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils.benchmark'` while importing `torch.utils.benchmark`. What could be the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to upgrade torch? I see you are using 1.4.0 but currently 1.9.0 is available.

`pip install torch --upgrade`

I have tested import of modules as you describe with 1.9.0 and receive no errors.